# Putting data from array into a view Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, arrays, output

I am trying to show data from a MySQL database in the form of a table in an android app. I have so far read all of the data from the table into arrays using the following code:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con =     
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","localhost","root");
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from stock");
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from stock");

ArrayList<Integer> stockNo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> stockName = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> stockQuantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> stockUnit = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> stockThreshold = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(result.next()){   
stockNo.add(result.getInt(1));
stockName.add(result.getString(2));
stockQuantity.add(result.getInt(3));
stockUnit.add(result.getString(4));
stockThreshold.add(result.getInt(5));
}
}
```

**My question is How do I now put the data from my array into my table layout View?**

It it good practice to store all text as a @string resource, so is there a way to to my array values like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of five ArrayList, could you encapsulate these five attributes in a new Class?

```
public class Stock{
        public int number;
        public String name;
        public int quantity;
        public String unit;
        public int stockThreshold;
}
```

And replace your while loop:

```
ArrayList<Stock> stockList = new ArrayList<MainActivity.Stock>();
while(result.next()){
    Stock stock = new Stock();
    stock.number = result.getInt(1);
    stock.name = result.getString(2);
    stock.quantity = result.getInt(3);
    stock.unity = result.getString(4);
    stock.stockThreshold = result.getInt(5);
    stockList.add(stock);
    }
```

Why are you using a TableLayout? You should be careful about memory consumption and avoid creating unecessary multiple views. I recommend implementing a custom adapter and Gridlayout, please take a look at this tutorial (GridView Custom Adapter example):

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! I have tried implementing your method but I get an error on the new ArrayList<MainActivity.Stock>(); saying it "cannot be resolved to a type", do you know why this is?

Comment: Yes I know, you should add Stock as a separated Class and change the <MainActivity.Stock> to <"put here you class name">, It should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done at the following way:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","localhost","root");
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from stock");
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from stock");
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
while(result.next()){
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    TextView stockNo = new TextView(this);
    TextView stockName = new TextView(this);
    TextView stockQuantity = new TextView(this);
    TextView stockUnit = new TextView(this);
    TextView stockThreshold = new TextView(this);
    stockNo.setText(String.valueOf(result.getInt(1)));
    stockName.setText(String.valueOf(result.getInt(2)));
    stockQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(result.getInt(3)));
    stockUnit.setText(String.valueOf(result.getInt(4)));
    stockThreshold.setText(String.valueOf(result.getInt(5)));
    tableRow.addView(stockNo);
    tableRow.addView(stockName);
    tableRow.addView(stockQuantity);
    tableRow.addView(stockUnit);
    tableRow.addView(stockThreshold);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}
```